# get no debug on why my role is not triggered from my ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, vagrant

I have a Vagrant infra to test ansible roles.

Here is my playbook

```
luis@spinoza:~/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11$ more tests/playbook_test_doc.yml
---
- name: Debug role path content
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: List role directory content
    command: tree ../../../ansible/mz_sphinx_documentation
    delegate_to: localhost

- name: Test Sphinx Documentation Role
  hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: true

  vars:
    zf_group: example_group
    project: example_project

  roles:
    - ../../../ansible/mz_sphinx_documentation
luis@spinoza:~/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11$
```

and here is my single file ansible role:

```
luis@spinoza:~/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11$ cat tests/../../../ansible/mz_sphinx_documentation/main.yml
---
- name: mz_sphinx_documentation
  hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: true

  vars:
    root_path: 
      doc: "/opt/_static/{{ zf_group }}_{{ project }}"

  tasks:
    - name: create folder
      file:
        path: "{{ root_path['doc'] }}"
        owner: "fox"
        group: "fox"
        state: directory
    
    - name: copy _build/html static files to remote host
      synchronize:
        src: "{{ playbook_dir }}/../_build/html/"
        dest: "{{ root_path['doc'] }}"
        archive: yes
        recursive: yes
    
    - name: set fox permissions
      file:
        path: "{{ root_path['doc'] }}"
        owner: "fox"
        group: "fox"
        recurse: yes

luis@spinoza:~/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11$
```

This is how I run it (I get **Sentinel found! Not provisioning.**):

```
vagrant provision --debug --provision-with tests/playbook_test_doc.yml > /tmp/log.txt 2>&1
luis@spinoza:~/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11$ grep -i  Sentinel /tmp/log.txt 
 INFO provision: Ignoring sentinel check, forcing provision
 INFO provision: Checking provisioner sentinel file...
 INFO provision: Sentinel found! Not provisioning.
luis@spinoza:~/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11$
```

Earlier I just run the vagrant test vm with:

```
luis@spinoza:~/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11$ vagrant up --provider=libvirt
...
luis@spinoza:~/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11$ 


luis@spinoza:~/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11$ cat Vagrantfile 
ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'libvirt'

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "debian/bullseye64"
  config.vm.provider :libvirt do |libvirt|
    libvirt.channel :type => 'unix', :target_name => 'org.qemu.guest_agent.0', :target_type => 'virtio'
    libvirt.memory = 2048
    libvirt.cpus = 2
  end

  config.vm.synced_folder '../', '/vagrant', type: 'nfs'
  config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
luis@spinoza:~/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11$
```

The `ansible.cfg` is set correctly:

```
luis@spinoza:~/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11$ cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
roles_path = /home/luis/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/ansible/

luis@spinoza:~/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11$ tree /home/luis/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/ansible/mz_sphinx_documentation/
/home/luis/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/ansible/mz_sphinx_documentation/
└── main.yml

0 directories, 1 file
luis@spinoza:~/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11$
```

and if I run `ansible-playbook` explicitly I still have no execution at the role level `ansible/mz_sphinx_documentation` with no explanation neither debug on way the role is not executed:

```
luis@spinoza:~/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11$ ansible-playbook -vv tests/playbook_test_doc.yml -i .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory 
ansible-playbook 2.10.8
  config file = /home/luis/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/luis/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.10.12 (main, Jun 11 2023, 05:26:28) [GCC 11.4.0]
Using /home/luis/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11/ansible.cfg as config file
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.

PLAYBOOK: playbook_test_doc.yml *********************************************************************************************************
2 plays in tests/playbook_test_doc.yml

PLAY [Debug role path content] **********************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/luis/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11/tests/playbook_test_doc.yml:2
ok: [default]
META: ran handlers

TASK [List role directory content] ******************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/luis/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11/tests/playbook_test_doc.yml:5
changed: [default] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["tree", "../../../ansible/mz_sphinx_documentation"], "delta": "0:00:00.001651", "end": "2023-08-20 03:09:54.699501", "rc": 0, "start": "2023-08-20 03:09:54.697850", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "../../../ansible/mz_sphinx_documentation\n└── main.yml\n\n0 directories, 1 file", "stdout_lines": ["../../../ansible/mz_sphinx_documentation", "└── main.yml", "", "0 directories, 1 file"]}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY [Test Sphinx Documentation Role] ***************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/luis/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11/tests/playbook_test_doc.yml:9
ok: [default]
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************
default                    : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

luis@spinoza:~/proj/g/infra/mz_devops/vagrant/deb11$
```

Comment: a better version of this question exist here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76937625/get-no-debug-on-why-a-role-is-not-triggered-from-the-ansible-playbook